# Rochambeaua Game (String Output)

Tags: java, string, math

I am trying to create a Rochambeau game.  I am stuck on the query lastThrow.  This query will take the throws from the computer and player and output "Computer throws ::Rock, Paper, or Scissors::"  The last part is supposed to refer back to a makeThrow query. My lastThrow method is always putting "Rock" whether or not that is what the player/computer throws.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.util.Random;

public class RochambeauPlayer{

  public int wins;
  public String name;
  public int lastThrow;
  public int throwMade;

  public RochambeauPlayer(java.lang.String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public java.lang.String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public int getWins(){
    return wins;
  }

  public void incrementWins(){
    wins++;
  }

  public int makeThrow(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int throwMade = rand.nextInt(3);
    Rochambeau.rock = 0;
    Rochambeau.paper = 1;
    Rochambeau.scissors = 2;
    return throwMade;
  }

  public int makeThrow(int throwType){
// RETURNS RANDOM (SO COMPUTER DOESNT ALWAYS WIN)
    Random rand = new Random();
    int throwMade = rand.nextInt(3);
    if (throwType == Rochambeau.rock){
      return throwMade;
  } else if (throwType == Rochambeau.paper){
      return throwMade;
  } else if (throwType == Rochambeau.scissors){
      return throwMade;
  } else {
      return throwMade;
  }
}

public java.lang.String lastThrow(){
  if (throwMade == 0){
    return "Rock";
} else if (throwMade == 1){
    return "Paper";
} else if (throwMade == 2){
    return "Scissors";
} else {
    return "No Throw";
}
}


  public java.lang.String toString(){
    return name + " has " + wins + " win(s).";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`throwMade` is not reassigned as global variable scope as its declared as local variable in method.

Remove declartion of local varible `throwMade` from both the methods : `makeThrow(int throwType)` and `makeThrow()` method.

i.e.

```
throwMade = rand.nextInt(3); //just assign not declare
instead of 
int throwMade = rand.nextInt(3);
```

Any varible declared as global and also with same name in local method. both are different variable and limited to scope only.

Comment: If I do that, what do I change the throwMade from my lastThrow method into ?

Comment: Refer updated anwser. just assign value not declare variable again in method.

Comment: I did that, but now Im getting a error saying that throwMade isn't a variable and cannot be found.

Comment: `throwMade` declartion is required at class level but not in method level. verify does it declared into ` public int throwMade;` below ` public int lastThrow;` or you removed!!